# HFS on Snow Leopard read only

Tags: disk-utility

Snow Leopard seems to have dropped support for the HFS (not HFS+) filesystem in Disk Utility. I have an HFS disk image that I created on a Leopard system. In Snow Leopard, this disk image is read only. I also can't create a new HFS disk image in Disk Utility, the option is missing.

Is there a way to mount or create an HFS disk image as read/write in Snow Leopard? (Perhaps a `diskutil` command?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ability has been removed from Snow Leopard.  It is possible with a 3rd party tool.

What you need is [FuseHFS](http://namedfork.net/fusehfs).